# pusher client receives an event, does nothing

Tags: javascript, laravel, pusher-js

The Pusher javascript client receives events, according to the Pusher log.  Successful resolution of the received event would currently do a javascript alert and console.log.  But nothing happens.

### The initial Pusher logging messages seem fine.

start Pusher log messages

```
Pusher :  : ["Connecting",{"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws-us2.pusher.com:443/app/92f31ffb6f7237036b92?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.0.1&flash=false"}] logger.ts:19:21
Pusher :  : ["State changed","initialized -> connecting"] logger.ts:19:21
Pusher :  : ["Connecting",{"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws-us2.pusher.com:443/app/92f31ffb6f7237036b92?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.0.1&flash=false"}] logger.ts:19:21
Pusher :  : ["State changed","connecting -> connected with new socket ID 30053.546066"] logger.ts:19:21
Pusher :  : ["Event sent",{"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"","channel":"bittids-messages-230427"}}] logger.ts:19:21
Pusher :  : ["Event recd",{"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","channel":"bittids-messages-230427","data":{}}]
```

### end pusher log messages

### The event makes it to the pusher server, according to the Pusher Debug console.

Pusher debug console info

```
API message
Channel: private-chat, Event: App\Events\MessageSent
```

### end Pusher debug console info

The data associated with the Pusher debug console event seems fine.

### The Pusher logger messages say event sent and event received.  But there is no data received or sent.  And nothing happens

```
Pusher :  : ["Event sent",{"event":"pusher:ping","data":{}}] logger.ts:19:21
Pusher :  : ["Event recd",{"event":"pusher:pong","data":{}}]
```

---

Although I am using Laravel 10, it was not working with Laravel Echo, so I tried vanilla javascript.  Either one working would be fine.

here is the vanilla js code.

```
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/8.0.1/pusher.min.js"></script>

<script>
  // this script is from
  // https://dashboard.pusher.com/apps/redacted/getting_started
  
   Pusher.logToConsole = true;
var pusher = new Pusher("redacted", {
      cluster: "us2", 
  // the next four lines are from 
  // https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/get-started-with-pusher-using-private-channels--cms-31253
  // when other stuff works, try uncommenting
      auth: {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': "redacted"
        }
    }
    });


var channel = pusher.subscribe('redacted, consistent with the name of the channel I used when I created the channel in Pusher');
//var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-chat');

 // Some useful debug msgs
 
pusher.connection.bind('connecting', function() {
      alert('Connecting to Pusher...');
    });
    pusher.connection.bind('connected', function() {
      alert('Connected to Pusher!');
    });
    pusher.connection.bind('failed', function() {
      alert('Connection to Pusher failed :(');
    });
    channel.bind('subscription_error', function(status) {
      alert('Pusher subscription_error');
    });
channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
     alert('successfully subscribed!');
 });

//channel.bind('App\\Events\\MessageSent', function(data){
channel.bind('MessageSent', (data) =>{
  alert("from pusher API,  " + data.message.message);
  console.log("from pusher API, pusher works!");
 
});

</script>
```

Comment: I found the problem.  in the Laravel routes/channels.php file, I did not include the path to the Auth facade use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;